# Best practice for managing a whitelist of ips across multiple servers with iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, cluster

I was wondering what the best practice for managing a whitelist of ip address across multiple servers? We want to allow our user base to add an ip address they want to whitelist through a web interface and then have that ip address added,deleted or modified to all servers.

I was thinking of programming a script to do it via python or bash and login into each server with keyless ssh and apply the rules but surely there must be a better method to achieve this.

Any advice?

Thanks all!

Comment: If they are all on the same logical network segment probably a external firewall between them all would be best.

Comment: Hi Matthew, they're not, they're in multiple datacenters.

Answer (score 1):

Use a configuration management tool. There are several to choose from.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations a configuration management tool?

Comment: @JohnNguyen Ansible or Salt are typically the easiest ones to get started with.